# Allow words enclosed in double quotes to be included in word count

Tags: jquery, regex

I am working on a jQuery function that counts the number of words in a textarea field. I want to be sure that words enclosed in double quotes (such as "this" or "that") are counted as one word each. Right now this is what I have:

```
    var maxWords = 100;
    $('#CommentsField').keypress(function() {
            var $this, wordcount;
            $this = $(this);
            wordcount = $this.val().split(/\s\b[\s,\.\'-:;]*/).length;

            if (wordcount > maxWords) {
                    alert("You've reached the maximum allowed words. Please keep the nominee description to 100 words.");
                    $('#WordCount').text("Word Count: "+maxWords);
                    return false;
            } else {
                return $('#WordCount').text("Word Count: "+wordcount);
            }
    });
```

This almost works, but it excludes words enclosed in double quotes, which messes up the word count. What am I missing from my regex that could fix this issue?

Comment: For the purpose of counting, you can just remove double quotes. And single quotes, as long as they don't have spaces around.

Comment: The current regex will never match since the word boundary will prevent it being between whitespace and non-word symbols. Are you sure `$this.val().match(/\S+/g).length` is not enough?

Comment: @stribizhev Yeah, that's what worked! I think I was making it harder than I needed it to be. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may count the number of occurrences of all sequences of non-whitespace characters in a string with

```
$this.val().match(/\S+/g).length
```

Note that a word boundary will fail the match if it is between non-word characters (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/lQ1mB3/1)).

**Another approach**: if your input is not Unicode, you can use just `/\b/g`, and divide the number of matches by 2.